# How do I redirect www.mypage.com/this/that to www.mypage.com in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis

```
<rule name="url rewrite"
                    stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="This/That/Something(.*)$" />
                <action type="Redirect"
                       url="" />
            </rule>
```

What do i put in the in the action url to just have it redirect to the current domain.

trying to turn www.mypage.com/this/that/whatever.aspx to this www.mypage.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to homepage, you can just use `/`. It will looks like that

```
<rule name="url rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="This/That/Something(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>
```

For ex. if you want to redirect to `www.mypage.com/abc`, you can use like that:

```
<rule name="url rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="This/That/Something(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/abc" />
</rule>
```

In case if you want to redirect to another domain `www.otherdomain.com`, you should use it like that:

```
<rule name="url rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="This/That/Something(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.otherdomain.com" />
</rule>
```